# Is there a workaround for this title bar color bug in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, maui

Why is the title bar changing colors and is there a workaround for this (presumable) bug?

To verify that this is can be reproduced I've created a new .NET MAUI project. I've added all the code of my fresh project below. It is a bit much but it's really just 3 pages, with buttons with a command that navigates using `Shell`. Nothing special. Page A and B can both navigate to C. The only difference: A navigates to C using an absolute path /B/C, while B navigates to C directly (push on stack). So under any circumstance, going back from page C always ends up on B.

What happens is this:
B > C > (backto)B = title bar on B stays the same
A > B/C > (backto)B = title bar on B changes background color to dark gray, unintended

The title bar does change back to normal, after navigating away from the page and then going back again. The title bar color change is not permanent throughout the apps lifecycle.

**Update**
This bug has been reported at the .NET MAUI issues section on Github.

**Preview**
Using the Pixel 5 Android 13 API 33 emulator: In this example I am using the devices' back button, but the same happens when using an on-page `<Button/>` in XAML with a command going back to page B instead. It makes no difference.

[image]

**AppShell**

```
<Shell
    x:Class="TitleBarTest.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleBarTest"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    <FlyoutItem Title="Title Bar Test">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                      Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="True"
                      Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"
                      Title="Page A" 
                      Route="MainPage"/>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SecondPage}"
                      Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="True"
                      Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"
                      Title="Page B"
                      Route="SecondPage"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ModalPage}"
                  Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                  Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
                  Title="Page C" 
                  Route="ModalPage"/>
</Shell>
```

**Page A**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleBarTest"
             x:DataType="local:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="TitleBarTest.MainPage"
             Title="Page A">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="List of A-items"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button
                Command="{Binding GoToModalViaSecondPageCommand}"
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Go to C via B"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel A:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Command GoToModalViaSecondPageCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        GoToModalViaSecondPageCommand = new Command(GoToModalViaSecondPage);
    }

    public async void GoToModalViaSecondPage()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SecondPage)}/{nameof(ModalPage)}");
    }
}
```

**Page B**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleBarTest"
             x:DataType="local:SecondPageViewModel"
             x:Class="TitleBarTest.SecondPage"
             Title="Page B">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="List of B-items"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button
                Command="{Binding GoToModalDirectlyCommand}"
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel B:

```
public class SecondPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Command GoToModalDirectlyCommand { get; private set; }

    public SecondPageViewModel()
    {
        GoToModalDirectlyCommand = new Command(GoToModalDirectly);
    }

    public async void GoToModalDirectly()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ModalPage)}");
    }
}
```

**Page C**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleBarTest"
             x:DataType="local:ModalPageViewModel"
             x:Class="TitleBarTest.ModalPage"
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
             BackgroundColor="#AA000000"
             Title="Page C">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White"
               CornerRadius="24"
               HeightRequest="256"
               Margin="0,0,0,-24">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label 
                    Text="Create new B-item"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel C:

```
public class ModalPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Command BackToPageBCommand { get; private set; }

    public ModalPageViewModel()
    {
        BackToPageBCommand = new Command(BackToPageB);
    }

    public async void BackToPageB()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SecondPage)}");
    }
}
```

**Styles.xaml**
In response to FreakyAlis' comment: The `Shell.BackgroundColor` is defined in *Styles.xaml* by default and when I remove this, *all* title bars have this gray color. It seems like there is a "fall back" color defined somewhere. This is the default:

```
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
    ...
    ...
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you changing the Shell's background color somewhere?

Comment: @FreakyAli I haven't changed any defaults for this new .NET MAUI project, but the shell.backgroundcolor is being changed in the style resources file. I have edited my question to include this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try something, changed the assignment for this to be just one of the two colors, I have a feeling your AppTheme is changing somehow and that's changing it from Violet to Gray

Comment: Removing `Shell.BackgroundColor` entirely from _Styles.xaml_ changes the title bar color to the "bug" gray shade everywhere in the app, instead of only on Page B after navigating back. I suspect there is some sort of "fall back" color defined somewhere. There are no other Shell background colors defined anywhere. Neither are there any gray shades defined in the (Android) platform specific resources values directory. I'm unable to test on Mac/iOS to see if it also happens there.

Comment: @AlJohn Thanks for the detailed information. However, I test your code and it works well. May I know the version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes, I am currently using VS 2022 - 17.5.5 and .NET 7.0 for the new app project I created

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: I have updated to VS22 v17.6.5 by this time and did not find any solutions yet.

Comment: John, this could be a potential issue, consider raising [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github.

Comment: Already on it, thanks!

Comment: @AlJohn No worries, hopefully it'll be fixed soon!